# Getter caling member object's getter

Tags: java, getter

sorry if this question already have an answer, because I don't know how to name it properly to search.
If yes, please share a link.

Say I have a class:

```
class A{
    int x;
    int getX(){return x;}
}
```

and another

```
class B{
    A a;
    A getA(){return a;}
}
```

and now using it:

```
class Test{
    void doSomething(B b){};
}
```

Is it good practice to write in class B getter like this:

```
int getX(){
    return a.getX();
}
```

and in doSomething:

```
b.getX();
```

Or better in doSomething call it like:

```
b.getA().getX();
```

Or maybe it doesn't make any difference in terms of good design?
Thanks.

Comment: This may ultimately be opinion-based, but what you're referring to has a name and lots of discussion around the internet: [The Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)  (Which recommends the approach of `b.getX()`)

Comment: `b.getA().getX();` one is good because method chaining is better.

Comment: In addition to @David's comment, I will note that in real-world practice it will depend very much on the specifics; if, for example, `A` is `ComplexNumber`, then everyone will definitely treat it as a single multi-aspect value, but if it is a service object, then the case for wrapping `getX` is much stronger.

Comment: Thank you guys for the response. I think now I got the idea when to use what.